# My animation is visible after opening my navigation bar

Tags: html, css, animation

I am creating a web page for school, and on my front page i have a name animation and a navigation button/bar. After opening the navigation bar, the animation is still shown over the navigation bar.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLpaB.png)

I have asked my teacher and he doesnt know.
I cant press the navigations buttons either, I only press the animation text, so it seems it is over the navigation bar.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="no">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Hjemmeside</title>
        <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .wrapper{
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #000000, #ffffff);
      /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
      /* clip-path: circle(25px at calc(0% + 45px) 45px); */
      clip-path: circle(25px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    #active:checked ~ .wrapper{
      clip-path: circle(75%);
    }
    .menu-btn{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 2;
      right: 20px;
      /* left: 20px; */
      top: 20px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #000000, #ffffff);
      /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    #active:checked ~ .menu-btn{
      background: #fff;
      color: #1c2541;
    }
    #active:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before{
      content: "\f00d";
    }
    .wrapper ul{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .wrapper ul li{
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .wrapper ul li a{
      color: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      padding: 5px 30px;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      line-height: 50px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    .wrapper ul li a:after{
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: 50px;
      transform: scaleY(0);
      z-index: -1;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    }
    .wrapper ul li a:hover:after{
      transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    .wrapper ul li a:hover{
      color: #000000;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]{
      display: none;
    }
    .content{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: -1;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      color: #202020;
    }
    .content .title{
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .content p{
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    /*Name shine*/
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    
    #name_shine {
      position: relative;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 15vw;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #ffffff, #000);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 80%;
      animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
      background-clip: border-box;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    
    @keyframes animate {
      0% {
        background-position: -500%;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 500%;
      }
    }
        </style>
        
    </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="active" />
          <label for="active" class="menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
              <li><a href="hobbyer.html">Hobbyer</a></li>
              <li><a href="kommune.html">Kommune</a></li>
              <li><a href="testpage.html">Test Page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bildegalleri</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p id="name_shine">Lukas Heen Berge</p>
        <script>
         
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You'll need to include your code, otherwise how can anybody know what's wrong with it?

Comment: Check the `z-index` of the animation section and the navigation bar, I think the animation section has a higher `z-index` value, that is why it shows above the navigation.

Comment: Your question lacks enough detail for anyone to give help that is likely to be useful. Please read the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [ask] for guidance on editing your question to make it possible and easy for people to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give each element a proper `z-index` value, like `z-index:0;`  for `#name_shine`, `z-index:2;` for `.wrapper`, and `z-index:3;` for  `.menu-btn`.

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="no">
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Hjemmeside</title>
        <style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');
    *{
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    }
    .wrapper{
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #000000, #ffffff);
      /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
      /* clip-path: circle(25px at calc(0% + 45px) 45px); */
      clip-path: circle(25px at calc(100% - 45px) 45px);
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
      z-index:2; 
    }
    #active:checked ~ .wrapper{
      clip-path: circle(75%);
    }
    .menu-btn{
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 3;
      right: 20px;
      /* left: 20px; */
      top: 20px;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 50px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      background: linear-gradient(-135deg, #000000, #ffffff);
      /* background: linear-gradient(375deg, #1cc7d0, #2ede98); */
      transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    }
    #active:checked ~ .menu-btn{
      background: #fff;
      color: #1c2541;
    }
    #active:checked ~ .menu-btn i:before{
      content: "\f00d";
    }
    .wrapper ul{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    .wrapper ul li{
      margin: 15px 0;
    }
    .wrapper ul li a{
      color: none;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: 500;
      padding: 5px 30px;
      color: #fff;
      position: relative;
      line-height: 50px;
      transition: all 0.3s ease;
    }
    .wrapper ul li a:after{
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50px;
      left: 0;
      border-radius: 50px;
      transform: scaleY(0);
      z-index: -1;
      transition: transform 0.3s ease;
    }
    .wrapper ul li a:hover:after{
      transform: scaleY(1);
    }
    .wrapper ul li a:hover{
      color: #000000;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"]{
      display: none;
    }
    .content{
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      z-index: -1;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100%;
      color: #202020;
    }
    .content .title{
      font-size: 40px;
      font-weight: 700;
    }
    .content p{
      font-size: 35px;
      font-weight: 600;
    }
    
    /*Name shine*/
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #000;
    }
    
    #name_shine {
      position: relative;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 15vw;
      letter-spacing: 4px;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #000, #ffffff, #000);
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: 80%;
      animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
      background-clip: border-box;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
      -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
      z-index:0;
    }
    
    @keyframes animate {
      0% {
        background-position: -500%;
      }
      100% {
        background-position: 500%;
      }
    }
        </style>
        
    </head>
      <body>
        <div>
          <input type="checkbox" id="active" />
          <label for="active" class="menu-btn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></label>
          <div class="wrapper">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
              <li><a href="hobbyer.html">Hobbyer</a></li>
              <li><a href="kommune.html">Kommune</a></li>
              <li><a href="testpage.html">Test Page</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Bildegalleri</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <p id="name_shine">Lukas Heen Berge</p>
        <script>
         
        </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```